# Ubuntu 12.04 alsamixer not found

Tags: 12.04, alsa, soundcard

I have a Lenovo Y500 with Windows 8.  I successfully got Ubuntu 12.04 installed alongside Windows 8 and the nvidia drivers just worked from the start.  The sound wasn't working at all however, and although alsamixer was alive and well when I started out, I seemed to have completely destroyed it now.

I keep getting:

```
$ alsamixer
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

Kernel version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux laptop 3.5.0-28-generic #48~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 24 21:42:24 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've tried both of the following packages from https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+packages:

```
oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms - 0.201305101424~precise1
oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-quantal-dkms - 0.201305101424~precise1
```

but to no avail.

This is the output of my alsa-info:

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=09851ab8c4380c25feaea7ff1de68d847bd4160c

I've tried many other solutions as well but nothing seems to get alsamixer back, nevermind trying to get the audio to work again.

PS.  when alsamixer was still working I did check the levels and it was not a case of the channels being muted.

**Edit**

1. /usr/bin is in $PATH.
2. no asound rc or conf files anywhere.
3. alsamixer is in /usr/bin, can't run it as alsamixer, /usr/bin/alsamixer not with sudo, even after purging and re-installing alsa-utils.

**Edit 2**

```
$ ls /dev/mixer -l
ls: cannot access /dev/mixer: No such file or directory
$ ls /usr/bin -l | grep alsamixer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root       65344 Mar 28 23:54 alsamixer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root       61272 Dec 18  2011 gnome-alsamixer
```

**Edit 3**

```
$ ls /dev/snd -l
ls: cannot access /dev/snd: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try to delete **asound.conf** file.

Comment: @Radu I do not have a asound.conf file.

Comment: Those `Unknown symbol` errors indicate that you have installed drivers that do not match your kernel.

Comment: @Radu Wow man this is a coincidence, I joined here actually to thank you for your guide on installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8 but didn't have enough rep to comment!  So, thanks!

Comment: Edit your question with the results of `ls /dev/mixer -l` and `ls /usr/bin -l | grep alsamixer` commands.

Comment: @skepticscript Does `gnome-alsamixer` working in terminal?

Comment: @Radu It opens up, but it crashes as soon as I try to configure it.

Comment: @skepticscript Edit again with result of `ls /dev/snd -l`

Comment: @Radu `lsmod | grep snd` also doesn't come up with anything.

Comment: @skepticscript This is very strange. Maybe is better to report this problem as a [bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: @Radu I might be the cause of the bug with all my tinkering.  Will try a clean install first.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firts of all, you should check if you have `/usr/bin` directory in your `$PATH` in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) with:

```
echo $PATH
```

If the `$PATH` is ok, check if `alsamixer` is there:

```
ls -l /usr/bin | grep alsamixer
```

If yes, try to run `alsamixer` like this:

```
/usr/bin/alsamixer
```

If still doesn't work delete  `.asoundrc` file (in your home directory) and `/etc/asound.conf` (if you have them) and reinstall `alsa-utils`:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install alsa-utils
```

Comment: I updated my question with the results.  After reading your guide to installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8 I have a lot of faith in you! ;D

Comment: Updated my answer again.  On my other PC with Ubuntu 12.04 installed ls /dev/mixer -l doesn't show anything either.

Comment: Marking this as the solution as it brought me to the final conclusion.

Comment: Radu, thank you very much. The simple checks and your `if/else` guide was spot on. The final solution (purge and install again) resolved a 3 week long issue I was struggling to resolve. So nice to see alsamixer again. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I hit this error and solved it by adding myself to the `audio` group.

```
sudo addgroup <username> audio
```

Log out and back in, then test.

Comment: It might be enough to just run `newgrp audio` and log out && log in, at least within the same shell.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it happened while the sound card (ALC662) was disabled in BIOS.
Enabling it, allowed me to start alsamixer.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Could you explain it a bit more and maybe add screenshots?

Comment: This might have helped, however I just re-installed and started over.

Answer (score 1):

For me using the -c parameter worked

```
alsamixer -c 1
```

*but I'm on 16.04*