# Why is there no sound(not even alsamixer) in my Mac Mini ?

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa, mac-mini

I have a Mac mini early 2007. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS i386 without using the bootcamp and just erasing all partitions(I mean there is no OS X on disk but only Ubuntu.). I have had no problems. Everything is working perfectly but **there is no sound**. On the tray bar there is sound indicator and seems like sound is working but somehow I couldn't get sound from my speakers. At the `System settings` when I click `Sound`-->`Test Sound`, there is no sound. I searched on Google and found some articles. I tried them out but still no sound.

I tried typing this in a terminal:-

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

and added these lines to that file:-

> snd_aoa_i2sbus
>
> snd_aoa_fabric_layout
>
> snd_aoa_codec_tas
>
> snd_aoa_codec_onyx

but no fix yet. Also I tried `alsamixer` but it wont open stating:-

> No such file or directory

I tried the solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294807/ubuntu-12-04-alsamixer-not-found%22) but still no fix. Now What can I do to fix my sound ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+t and type `alsamixer`. You will get a terminal based tool for configuring your Sound card . Now try changing the settings there and get back to us.

Comment: Hi Venki, thanks for your kindly response when i type alsamixer and enter on terminal system says cannot open mixer: No such file or directory, i also tryed after sudo su and result was the same.

Comment: Whoa! That is the issue here i suppose. did you try `sudo apt-get install alsamixer` ?(i.e did you try installing alsamixer?)

Comment: yes i did, last night i google it the problem and found some articles about it, i try every step but the result is the same, is there any possibility to do something wrong during installation ? i mean should i try to format and re-install ?

Comment: "I try every step but the result is the same"- Which article did you exactly try out and what was the result of it exactly?(Add the info reg. this to your question's description)

Comment: i use this one "http://askubuntu.com/questions/294807/ubuntu-12-04-alsamixer-not-found" and found some forums which peoples says user must be added to sound group and i did that allready.

Comment: [This comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/294807/ubuntu-12-04-alsamixer-not-found%22#comment370640_294807) in that link you have given says what you say above - You might try reinstalling. But before that, try remembering if you recently installed some driver to your Mac. It might be that, that driver doesn't support your kernel and is causing the issue. Also you might try clearing some cache(and maybe try updating your system too). If that doesn't work, maybe you can wait for help, else reinstall Ubuntu.(After you found a fix, please make it an answer here and accept it! :-) )

Comment: i did re-install the ubuntu again and updated everything but the result was the same, there were no sound. So i plug-in my usb sound card and it worked. So i fixed problem with my usb soundcard. I don't think problem cause by ubuntu, because my mac-mini is early 2007 and it's very old though.Ubuntu is fantastic operating system, thanks to developers, testers and you guys again to make me meet with this beauty OS and for your help, god bless you all. And special thanks to Venki to let me torture him with my poor english and grammar :)

Comment: If you think you've fixed it, please post it as an answer by clicking the *Post Answer* button. It would benefit you and the community greatly!

Comment: @impinball you are right, marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved with USB Soundcard (12$).