# Audio drops after a few minutes

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa

Audio drops after a few minutes of music playback. After that if I run Audacious I get this error:

```
ALSA error: snd_mixer_attach failed: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Any messages in the system log?

Answer (score 0):

I used the method from the second answer here: [Ubuntu 12.04 alsamixer not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294807/ubuntu-12-04-alsamixer-not-found)

```
sudo addgroup <username> audio
```